# How to implement infinite scroll in my vue js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I currently learning combining laravel with vue. This page should be fetching post data from server and showing in user timeline. I am successfully get all data and display it. But i want to implement a infinite scroll into it but i had no idea how to do it. i had been tried many different way also not working. Maybe is my knowledge about vue is still fresh. Any suggestion for me?

Here is my original code :[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masterhunter/67dx8vs5/)

Here is code i try to implement infinite scroll with this [example](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/#!/getting-started/hacker-news) .

[jsfiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/masterhunter/stut5etv/)

The scrolling symbol is showing but seem like the array did't not passing , the data still appear all in one time.

Once submitted `/feed` the server will return array which contain post information. But i don't know how to passing into the list array.

Returned Array

In vue
[image]

In route
[image]

Comment: you need to show what failed/didn't work. :)

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal thank for reply. i updated my code, please have a look.

Comment: can anyone answer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825170/how-to-make-infinite-scroll-loader-in-vue-js-using-data-in-props

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Installation:

```
npm install vue-infinite-scroll --save
```

Registration in your main.js:

```
// register globally
var infiniteScroll =  require('vue-infinite-scroll');
Vue.use(infiniteScroll)

// or for a single instance
var infiniteScroll = require('vue-infinite-scroll');
new Vue({
  directives: {infiniteScroll}
})
```

Your html:

```
<div v-infinite-scroll="loadMore" infinite-scroll-disabled="busy" infinite-scroll-distance="10">
  ...
</div>
```

You component:

```
var count = 0;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [],
    busy: false
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore: function() {
      this.busy = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        for (var i = 0, j = 10; i < j; i++) {
          this.data.push({ name: count++ });
        }
        this.busy = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i followed your instruction but the infinite scroll still not working.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67dx8vs5/2/)

Comment: In my laravel 5.4 reshources/assets/js/app.js has registered with this.
`require('vue-infinite-scroll');
Vue.use(infiniteScroll)`  
`const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    directives: {infiniteScroll},
    store
});`

Comment: Check this out! https://github.com/ElemeFE/vue-infinite-scroll It should help :) @masterhunter

Comment: It's really helpful .
Do you have idea how to call method on scroll to top?
Thanks

Comment: does this really need a library

Comment: @PirateApp Why not? Take a look at the implementation: https://github.com/ElemeFE/vue-infinite-scroll/blob/master/src/directive.js

Comment: is there a way to use in reverse order? i mean render the new posts in top chronological order

Comment: this literally just copy paste from vue-infinite-scroll documentation.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to setup a locking mechanism to stop rapid requests to your backend. The lock would be enabled before a request is made, and then the lock would be disabled when the request has been completed and the DOM has been updated with the new content (which extends the size of your page).

For example:

```
new Vue({
// ... your Vue options.

ready: function () {
var vm = this;
var lock = true;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (endOfPage() && lock) {
    vm.$http.get('/myBackendUrl').then(function(response) {
      vm.myItems.push(response.data);
      lock = false;
    });
  };
});
```

};
   });

Another thing to keep in mind is that the scroll event is triggered more than you really need it to (especially on mobile devices), and you can throttle this event for improved performance. This can efficiently be done with requestAnimationFrame:

```
;(function() {
 var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
    obj = obj || window;
    var running = false;
    var func = function() {
        if (running) { return; }
        running = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
            running = false;
        });
    };
    obj.addEventListener(type, func);
};

/* init - you can init any event */
throttle ("scroll", "optimizedScroll");
})();

// handle event
window.addEventListener("optimizedScroll", function() {
console.log("Resource conscious scroll callback!");
});
```

Comment: your missing endOfPage() method

Answer (score 1):

I also tried the Vue-infinite-scroll, but it's not working properly when aligning with Vue-router, at least in my code.
So I came up with my own solution.

```
<template>
  <div ref="loadmore" class="infinite-container">
      <!-- the inifite container -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      timer: null,
      // check if is in infinite procees
      busy: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    infiniteScrollHandler() {
        //check if container's bttom is overflow screen
      let bottomOff =
        this.$refs.loadmore.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - screen.height;
      if (bottomOff < 10 && !this.busy) {
        console.log("loading... " + new Date());
        this.busy = true;
        // do something 
        this.busy = false;
      }
    },
    setIntervalTimer() {
      //check every 500 milliseconds
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.infiniteScrollHandler();
      }, 500);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      // set up timer on mounted
    this.setIntervalTimer();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
      // do not forget clear the interval timer
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @ashishbansal's answer

for vue js 2... note I used ecma script 6 mostly... if you want to use old notation you have to convert

ready is now mounted

```
mounted() {
      let app = this;
      let distanceStartLoading = 300; //start loading stuff before reaching the very bottom right...

      var endOfPage = function endOfPage() {
            let bottomOfWindow = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.offsetHeight - distanceStartLoading;
            if (bottomOfWindow) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }
      ;(function () {
        var throttle = function (type, name, obj) {
          obj = obj || window;
          var running = false;
          var func = function () {
            if (running) {
              return;
            }
            running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(function () {
              obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
              running = false;
            });
          };
          obj.addEventListener(type, func);
        };

        /* init - you can init any event */
        throttle("scroll", "optimizedScroll");
      })();

      // handle event
      window.addEventListener("optimizedScroll", function () {
        console.log("scrolling but not endofpage");
        if (endOfPage()) {
          console.log("hellow");
        }
        ;
      });

    },
```